# How to create one sub query instead of union

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, union-all

I have a query like this, I feel it can be shorter and fester. has anybody a idea?

```
select * from table where match(col1) against('anything') and col2 in('10')
   union distinct
select * from table where match(col1) against('anything')
```

Now I want to know can I implement the above query using `sub-query` or `join`?

---

**Edit:** My query in reality: (focus on two first `select` clause)

```
SELECT @rank := @rank + 3 `rank`, id, subject, name, matnF, source, 'quran' which 
  FROM quran, (select @rank := -2) q
     WHERE MATCH (`translate`, subject, name) AGAINST (:q) and aye IN (" .implode(',', $matches[0]) . ")

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT @rank1 := @rank1 + 3 `rank`, id, subject, name, matnF, source, 'quran' which 
  FROM quran, (select @rank1 := -1) q 
     WHERE MATCH (`translate`, subject, name) AGAINST (:q)

UNION ALL

SELECT @rank2 := @rank2 + 3 `rank`, id, subject, byA, matnF, source, '' `translate`, 'hadith' which 
  FROM hadith, (select @rank2 := 0) q 
     WHERE MATCH (subject) AGAINST (:q)

ORDER BY rank LIMIT :j, 11
```

What I want it using `CASE WHEN ... THEN ...` for two first query and combine them.

---

**Edit2:** This is look like what I want:

```
(SELECT @rank1 := @rank1 + 2 `rank`, id, subject, name, matnF, source, 'quran' which 
  FROM quran, (select @rank1 := -1) q 
     WHERE MATCH (`translate`, subject, name) AGAINST (:q)
        ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN aye IN (" .implode(',', $matches[0]) . ") THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END
)

    UNION ALL

(SELECT @rank2 := @rank2 + 2 `rank`, id, subject, byA, matnF, source, '' `translate`, 'hadith' which 
      FROM hadith, (select @rank2 := 0) q 
         WHERE MATCH (subject) AGAINST (:q)
)

ORDER BY rank LIMIT :j, 11
```

Comment: since string is the same('anything')  in both cases,  why do you need union at all ?

Comment: @a1ex07 because the first query has `and col2 in('10')`

Comment: But the second one will return everything the first returns and some extra rows (where col2 not in ('10')).

Comment: @a1ex07 yes, I did it just for the `order`. I need to show the result of first query and then show ther result of second query

Comment: So you want some rows appear twice, correct ?

Comment: @a1ex07 good question, no actually I don't want duplicate rows. I will edit my question

Comment: You could just use `select * from table where match(col1) against('anything')` and call it good. The results from `select * from table where match(col1) against('anything') and col2 in('10')` will already be there in `select * from table where match(col1) against('anything')`

Comment: @zedfoxus you are right, but I need to show the result of first query in the top of results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If duplicates are not needed, the query below should give you desired output

```
select a.* 
from table1 a 
where match(col1) against('anything')
ORDER BY 
 CASE
  WHEN col2 IN ('10') THEN 0
  ELSE 1
 END
;
```

Comment: Thanks, +1.  just one thing, in reality my query is complex a but, may I give you  my real query and you do this on it?

Comment: Sure. For next time I'd recommend asking questions with minimal working example, so it will be easier to answer...

Comment: oh, it should be noted that I can not remove that variable `@rank`, because it is using to sort for another queries that are combined (using `union all`) to this query.

Comment: Correction: `@rank := @rank + 2` , `@rank1 := @rank1 + 2` *(in what I likned)*

Comment: Can you just modify your question and put the query there ?

Comment: @stack:  And please add how you want resultset to be sorted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174052/why-outer-order-by-does-not-work-correctly