# Why outer order by does not work correctly?

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, union-all

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT @rank := @rank + 3 `rank`, id, subject, name
  FROM quran, (select @rank := -2) q
     WHERE MATCH (subject, name) AGAINST ('anything') and aye IN ("10")

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT @rank1 := @rank1 + 3 `rank`, id, subject, name
  FROM quran, (select @rank1 := -1) q 
     WHERE MATCH (subject, name) AGAINST ('anything')

UNION ALL

SELECT @rank2 := @rank2 + 3 `rank`, id, subject, byA
  FROM hadith, (select @rank2 := 0) q 
     WHERE MATCH (subject) AGAINST ('anything')

ORDER BY rank LIMIT 0, 11
```

Now I optimized my query and combined tow first `SELECT` clause to one, like this: (because they have the same table name)

```
(SELECT @rank1 := @rank1 + 2 `rank`, id, subject, name
  FROM quran, (select @rank1 := -1) q 
     WHERE MATCH (subject, name) AGAINST ('anything') 
       ORDER BY CASE WHEN aye IN ('10') 
          THEN 0
          ELSE 1
       END
)

UNION ALL

(SELECT @rank2 := @rank2 + 2 `rank`, id, subject, byA
  FROM hadith, (select @rank2 := 0) q 
     WHERE MATCH (subject) AGAINST ('anything')
)

ORDER BY rank LIMIT 0, 11
```

But I don't know why the sort of result is not identical with the first query. Why? And how can I fix it?

---

**Edit:** Here is some examples:

```
// quran                               // hadith
+----+---------+--------+                +----+---------+-------+
| id | subject |  name  |                | id | subject |  byA  |
+----+---------+--------+                +----+---------+-------+
| 1  | hello   | jack   |                | 1  | blue    | jack  |
| 2  | blue    | peter  |                | 2  | how     | hello |
| 3  | jack    | red    |                | 3  | jack    | blue  |
| 4  | back    | blue   |                +----+---------+-------+
| 10 | jack    | how    |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Now, I want this **output:** So first priority is that `$number`, and then `subject` column and then `name` column, Also the result is alternating for both tables.

```
$anything = 'jack', $number = 10
+----+---------+--------+
| id | subject |  name  |
+----+---------+--------+
| 10 | jack    | how    |
| 3  | jack    | blue   |
| 3  | jack    | red    |
| 1  | blue    | jack   |
| 1  | hello   | jack   |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Comment: The queries look incredibly different to me.  In one case, you are incrementing by "2" and in the other by "3".  So, the ranks will be different.  Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok I want this: focus of first query: fist `select` and second `select` returns some duplicate rows, Now I want to prevent of this (In this case `UNION DISTINCT` works like `UNION ALL`). Also I think I can write one `select` instead of both two first `select` (because the table name is identical). Totally my purpose is sorting. I want to show the result of first `select` in the top of results.

Comment: I would prefer to see raw source of data and expected result set instead of all these weird queries :-)

Comment: @GordonLinoff btw, I use `rank` for sorting the results alternating. So surely I need to replace it with `2`, because I removed one `select` clause.

Comment: @Alex ok, I will add some tables ..

Comment: "I want to show the result of first select in the top of results.", you could just add an additional field for this purpose; something like `SELECT IF(aye IN ("10"), 0, 1) AS sortGroup, [etc....]`, you should even be able to keep the original `rank`ing logic in a similar manner.

Comment: @Uueerdo and where should I use of `sortGroup`?

Comment: @stack I added an answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added some data for more clarification. I like to *you* take a look at it please ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is the best way to go about things, but it is the least modification to your existing attempts.

```
(
  SELECT IF(aye IN ("10"), 0, 1) AS sortGroup
     , IF(aye IN ("10"), @rank := @rank + 3, @rank1 := @rank1 + 3) AS `rank`
     , id, subject, name
  FROM quran
     , (select @rank := -2) AS rq, (select @rank1 := -1) AS r1q  
  WHERE MATCH (subject, name) AGAINST ('anything') 
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT 2 AS sortGroup
     , @rank2 := @rank2 + 2 `rank`
     , id, subject, byA
  FROM hadith
     , (select @rank2 := 0) AS q 
  WHERE MATCH (subject) AGAINST ('anything')
)
ORDER BY sortGroup, rank 
LIMIT 0, 11
```

Actually, I am not positive you can merge the first two unioned queries and get the same results. In the original query, with `UNION DISTINCT` and the separate computation of rank in the original, records that satisfy the `aye IN ("10")` criteria will probably often appear twice (but with different rank values).

Comment: :-) ! This query is complex a bit, I tested it, and it has almost correct sorting and it is good. But time duration of it is more than my first query (three `select` clause). Anyway thanks. +1